# Problem with foreign key constraints and construction of Mysql DB

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, constraints, type-constraints

I'm having a problem with thinking of the way to connect two tables. 
I have one table with actions (RAD):

```
CREATE TABLE RAD (
  rad_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  spec_id INT NULL,
  predp_id INT NULL,
  predf_id INT NULL,
  strp_ID INT NULL,
  strf_ID INT NULL,
---more fileds---
  FOREIGN KEY (spec_id) REFERENCES SPEC(spec_id) ON DELETE SET NULL,    
  FOREIGN KEY (strp_ID) REFERENCES STRANKEP(strp_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (strf_ID) REFERENCES STRANKEF(strf_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (predp_id) REFERENCES PREDMETIP(predp_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (predf_id) REFERENCES PREDMETIF(predf_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

And one table of specifications (SPEC) based on whom bill will be made:

```
CREATE TABLE SPEC (
  spec_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   ---more fileds---    
) ENGINE=InnoDB COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

As you can see action rad_id(RAD) row will be deleted if any client (strp_ID or strf_ID) will be deleted. The same goes for case(predp_id and predf_id).

Now I want to restrict delete of action rad_id(RAD row) if its included in specification. Therefore, when specification is made it inserts spec_id(SPEC) in spec-id(RAD) filed.

When specification is deleted field goes back to null and that works. **BUT** it allows me to delete the action rad_id(RAD) when it was included in specification(SPEC) and has that foreign key spec_id included in RAD table. And I can not let that happen. It should delete only when its null and specification key is not present.

The problem is specification will contain MULTIPLE actions rad_id's(RAD) so I can not tie it with one more column rad_id(RAD) as foreign key.

I don't know how to approach this problem.

```
     RAD TABLE  
rad_id  spec_id
1       1
2       1
3       1
4       null

        SPEC TABLE  
spec_id     rad_id-reference
1           1,2,3
```

As seen above SPEC table row will be made out of 3 rad_id's, I need a way to say  rad_id's 1,2 and 3 can not be deleted if spec_id 1 exists. rad_id 4 can be deleted.

The problem is that I can not make rad_id-reference on SPEC table a FOREIGN KEY made out of 3 rad_id's.

Comment: I deleted my answer since the question is not clear to me anymore. Please create a running (and simple) example in SQL Fiddle, so I can help you better.

Comment: I have made little table with explanation.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50de2/1 Messy, but works, if you have another suggestion id appreciate.

Comment: I think I get the problem now. My take is that the fool proof solution is to create a pre-delete trigger (`BEFORE DELETE`) on the RAD table that verifies that "spec_id is null" before deleting the row. If it's not null, then the trigger will prevent the deletion. Is that what you need? See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: Yeah that would be great but Cascaded foreign key actions do not activate triggers :) . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041064/trigger-calls-in-cascade-deleting . And I have turned on cascading all over the db before knowing this. But yes you are right that would work in idle situations. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to do this. 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50de2/1 If you change a delete value into 1 it will fail.

```
     RAD TABLE  
rad_id-PK
1       
2       
3       
4       

        SPEC TABLE  
spec_id-PK
1
2

    RESTRICTDEL TABLE
res_id-PK  spec_id-FK  rad_id-FK
1           1           1
2           1           2
3           2           2
4           2           3
5           2           3
```

I have made another table that will contain both PK id's in one column, and they are FK's. one is PK and it will be unique just like spec_id From SPEC table. second is rad_id that can be double. I just have to set SET foreign_key_checks = 0; and back 1 when I'm done with inserting a new specification. 
Also will need to loop with php and for every rad_id make new resdel_id entry. 
This way multiple rad_id wont be deleted if there is one spec_id connecting them.